# Reducing TSP to HAM-CYCLE to VERTEX-COVER to CLIQUE to 3 CNF-SAT to SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

In [Cormen's Algorithms book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072970545) on NP-completeness they prove various problems are NP-complete by reducing a previously proved NP-complete problem (call $K$) to current problem (call $L$). Each proof involves some clever construction which reduces all instances of $K$ to few instances of $L$. Here is the proof order they follow. **CIRCUIT-SAT, SAT, 3 CNF-SAT, CLIQUE, VERTEX-COVER, HAM-CYCLE, TSP**. e.g. in reducing **VERTEX-COVER** to **HAM-CYCLE** they use a **widget** which does the trick.

After this [previous question of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/how-are-all-np-complete-problems-similar), I think one can reduce back. i.e. one can reduce **HAM-CYCLE** to **VERTEX-COVER** problem. I tried searching web for such reductions, but most of the link return the normal reduction order. I'm interested to see if one can reduce in **reverse order**. i.e. TSP to HAM-CYCLE to VERTEX-COVER to CLIQUE to 3 CNF-SAT to SAT

I'm looking for reverse constructive proofs. I know all of these problems belong to NP-complete hence equivalent.

You don't have to give complete proof as an answer. Proof sketches are fine too. If you can point me where these proofs are available online, that's completely fine too. I'm just trying to lean how constructions are leveraged among problems that look so different on surface. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you interested in such reduction? Note: The last reduction 3CNF-SAT to SAT is trivial (Every 3CNF-SAT formula is a SAT formula).

Comment: Well I found most reductions interesting because they are construction proofs. It's hard to think out-of-the-box constructions. So I wanted to see if reverse construction is possible.

Comment: What have *you* tried? All stated problems are $\mathsf{NP}$-Complete. Thus every problem in $\mathsf{NP}$ can be reduced to your problems (by definition of $\mathsf{NPC}$). Hint: Start reducing TSP to HAM-CYCLE.

Comment: @Chris As of now nothing. I mean till yesterday I was under impression that above isn't possible. Let me start with TSP to HAM-CYCLE :)

Comment: Note that not all NPC problems are equally hard, see e.g. [weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_NP-complete) vs [strongly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete) NP-completeness. Therefore, not all reductions are equally simple; those from strong to weak problems have to be complex enough to prevent e.g. efficient approximations to carry over (unless P=NP).

Comment: @Raphael, all of the mentioned problem by OP are strongly NP-C, so your comment makes no sense here.

Comment: I'd offer you to read [Garey & Johnson](http://www.amazon.com/Computers-Intractability-NP-Completeness-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0716710455) book, they provide iff proof for some of problems, proof techniques are not easy and you can't expect to solve them yourself in few days.

Comment: what's wrong with hamcycle->sat->3-sat->vertex cover?

Comment: @SashoNikolov nothing is wrong with it. If hamcycle to sat is a constructive proof that's fine. I'm looking for reductions which don't invoke Cook-Levin theorem.

Comment: but what is not constructive about Cook-Levin? it gives you a concrete construction: take you favorite verifier for hamcycle, encode it as a TM, build a SAT formula :) you want "simple" for some measure of simple?

Comment: @SashoNikolov the issue with going from hamcycle -> sat -> 3-sat -> vertex cover is the number of variables generated by the sat that makes it very obnoxious to deal with. I'd much rather deal with the clique problem itself than the sat for that reason, but that's just me.

Comment: @devinbost I *think* (it's been a long long time) I was trying to get Ankush to specify what his actual constraints on the reduction are. Your answer seems to be that you want small blow up in the formula size. That's reasonable. I am not sure if it was what Ankush was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of the ones you're looking at here are pretty simple actually (at least to sketch!). For all of these, there are many other ways to do it, even many other sensible ways, so these are just attempts to pick the simpler approaches (we'll see if I succeed).

As mentioned in one of the comments on the question, $3SAT$ to $SAT$ is trivial, an instance of $3SAT$ is already and instance of $SAT$, so there's no work needed at all.

To get from $VERTEX$ $COVER$ $(VC)$ to $CLIQUE$ we can do a couple of short jumps, that'll also put another problem in the loop. $VC$ is the *dual* of $INDEPENDENT$ $SET$ $(IS)$, that is, we can find a vertex cover of size $k$ in a graph $G$ iff we can find an independent set of size $n-k$ in $G$. Play around with this a little and you'll see why this is true. If we then take the edge-complement graph $\bar{G}$ of $G$, an independent set of size $t$ in $G$ is the same as a clique of size $t$ in $\bar{G}$, so that gets us to $CLIQUE$.